# AVAudiorecorder - no sound recording on iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudiorecorder, recording

I'm recording audio on every iOS simulator available and on some devices without any problems (for example iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1 or iPhone 4S with iOS 6.0.1), but recently I got feedback from my client telling me that audio recording on iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0.1 fails with no crash - they click record and nothing happens. Has anyone encountered that problem? Is this device specific? Or the usually working and widely used code for AVAudioRecorder needs to have some specific settings on this one device + system combination?

Comment: i also faced this problem.... :) when we clicked on recording then recording not perform... then we have to uninstall app from background and play again..:)

Comment: So after killing the app and running it again you managed to actually record the sound?

Comment: i did a lot of search and ask many question on SO but did not got any exact solution then i replace my recording code with new code...

Comment: first paste your recording code...then i will correct ..

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too and in my case PrepareToRecord() was failing because a folder in file's path was missing (not created yet).